# How to display data in Firebase RecyclerView UI from Firebase using Id's from Geofire

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui, geofire

I have an app I am working on that needs live queries using location from the user. Writing to the geofire node is okay but I have trouble on reading. Once I get the id's how do I make a query with them and display data using the firebase recycleradapter?
Here is my code so far (without Geofire):

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Venue> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Venue>()
                    .setQuery(filterRef, Venue.class)
                    .build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Venue, VenueViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public VenueViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.single_venue_item, parent, false);

            return new VenueViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final VenueViewHolder holder, final int position, Venue model) {

            final String venueName = model.getVenueName();
            holder.venueName.setText(venueName);

            Glide.with(holder.mView.getContext())
                    .load(model.getVenueMainImage())
                    .apply(new RequestOptions()
                            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round))
                    .into(holder.venueMainImage);

        }
    };

    venuesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    venuesRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: FirebaseUI has no built-in support for the join that is required to look up the item for each key. You'll probably need to create your own variant of `FirebaseIndexedArray`, which takes a GeoFire [GeoQuery](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/firebase/geofire/GeoQuery.java) instead of a Firebase Database `Query` that the `FirebaseIndexedArray` takes.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Any sample or link that I can check out? I have not worked with the indexed array on firebase yet

Comment: The link shows you the code for the `FirebaseIndexedArray`. There is no sample that modifies it for use with `GeoQuery` that I know of.

Comment: Oh my God, no way to combine Geofire and Firebase-recyclerview? I badly want that.